# Nginx direct sub domain to main domain

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I am hosting a wordpress blog at www.example.com, trying to do a hexo project at hexo.example.com

I put SSL configuration on nginx.conf in /etc/nginx folder as the certificate is a wildcard, I do not want to write it twice in two server block files.

I have one server block for example.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name www.example.com;

    root /var/www/html/example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
      access_log off;
      expires max;
    }

     location ~ /\.ht {
       deny  all;
     }

     location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

This server block will direct example.com and www.example.com to https://www.example.com and it works very well.

For the other server block hexo.example.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hexo.example.com;

    root /var/www/html/hexo.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

hexo.example.com  will be directed to main domain www.example.com.

Can anyone give me some advise what I can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to write it twice.

There could be some kind of configuration trickery that you could apply to avoid writing it twice, but that will be much more complex tat writing it twice. If such a trick can be implemented at all that is.

Comment: Hi Tero. Can you please tell me a little bit more about "write it twice"? I am not sure what it means. Thanks

Comment: Include the SSL certificate statements in both `server` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

> I put SSL configuration on nginx.conf in /etc/nginx folder as the certificate is a wildcard, I do not want to write it twice in two server block files.

Use [`include`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) directive.

1. Create a config file for your ssl configurations.

   ```
   -- ssl.conf

   ssl_certificate /path/to/your/certificate.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/certificate.key;
   ...snip...
   ssl_trusted_certificate /path/to/your/trust-chain.pem;
   ```
2. Include the config file in your virtual hosts configuration.

   ```
   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name example.com;

       location / {
           access_log off;
           return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
       }
   }

   server {
       listen 443 ssl;
       server_name www.example.com;

       ## put your SSL config file path you made earlier here
       include /path/to/ssl.conf;

       ... snip ...
   }

   server {
       listen 443 ssl;
       server_name hexo.example.com;

       ## again, put your SSL config file path here.
       include /path/to/ssl.conf;

       ... snip ...
   }
   ```

---

> hexo.example.com will be directed to main domain www.example.com.

No it won't.
If you need to redirect it, well just redirect it, like

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hexo.example.com;

    location / {
        access_log off;
        return 301 https://www.example.com;
    }
}
```